# Merge multiple excel files via python while keeping VBA and the Sheet structure intact

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl, xlwings

I have multiple xlsm Excel files I want to combine. All of them have multiple sheets and formulas and VBA Code. I want to merge all of those files into one big excel sheet, where I keep all of the sheets with all of the vba code and the excel formulas. All of this I want to do in python.

I tried to google some solution, but it was either only for xlsx files or it ignored the sheet structure.

Comment: Is the VBA code in the sheets (so basically event routines) or in separate modules?

Comment: It is in the sheets as well as in separate modules. @FunThomas

Comment: Then it's getting tricky, because you need to use the VBE to read the modules and inject them into the "big" file. Including checks that you don't have modules with duplicate names ("Module1"). No clue if this feasable with python.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this a while back, and saved it for sometime in the future.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\Merge Multiple Excel Files Into One File\\*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\Merge Multiple Excel Files Into One File\\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    print(all_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    df.shape
    df.to_excel("C:\\Merge Multiple Excel Files Into One File\\final.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')

# http://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html

########  ########  ########  ########  ########  ########  ########  ########  


import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["C:/Book1.xlsx", "C:/Book2.xlsx", "C:/Test/Book3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

# delete the first row for all frames except the first
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)

# Results go to the default directory if not assigned somewhere else.
# C:\\Users\\Excel\\.spyder-py3


# another option
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd()) + '\*.xlsx')
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1') for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
if you want to add the filename into the df too then,
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd()) + '\*.xlsx')
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1') for f in files]
file_names = [os.path.basename(f) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=file_names)
Using Pathlib module (recommended Python 3.4+)
from pathlib import Path
files = [f for f in Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx')]
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1')]
file_names = [f.stem for f in files] 
df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=file_names)
or as a one liner : 
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx')],keys=[f.stem for f in Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx')],sort=False)
```